# How to prevent inherit for H1?

Tags: html, css, xhtml

See the code below, I would like `<h1>` to use `.page-header h1` class but it using `#main h1`

How to prevent that without modifying `#main h1` ?

```
<div id='main'>
 <div class="page-header">
        <h1>This is a title</h1>
 </div>
</div>
```

css

```
#main h1 {
 line-height: 30px;
 font: 28px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 color: #333;
 font-weight: 300;
}

.page-header h1 {
    color: white;
    font-size: 28px;
    line-height: 20px;
    margin: 12px 0 11px 11px;
}
```

Comment: CSS specificity is the key topic to understand here, an `id` selector is more specific than a `class` selector. You should think about what you mean when you say "any h1 that is a descendant of an element with an ID of main should look *this* way". Because that's obviously not what you mean...

Comment: I enjoy this article on specificity.  It's entertaining and informative. http://www.stuffandnonsense.co.uk/archives/css_specificity_wars.html This article gathers the above link and more: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a more [specific](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#specificity) selector. Change the selector on your second rule to:

```
#main .page-header h1
```

Compare the specificity values for each selector:

```
#main h1               0101
.page-header h1        0011
#main .page-header h1  0111  <-- Winner!
```

Answer (score 1):

You can increase your specificity as bfavaretto answered, **or you can *reduce* your specificity**. This is especially true with an `h1` tag, as many (like me) are of the opinion that you should only have one `h1` tag on a web page. Holding to such a view, the reduction would obviously be:

```
h1 { all your properties }
```

The above could even be used with multiple `h1` tags, *assuming all of them reside within `#main` anyway* (then `#main h1` is superfluous), and *then* if you have specific styling for the `.page-header h1` the combination class will override the simple `h1` definition.

Comment: Definitely cleaner, but might break the layout depending on the current markup and CSS. +1 for cleanliness though!

Comment: @bfavaretto--yes, this definitely depends upon mark-up to which I am in the dark about (since the OP only gives the limited html code for his specific use).

Comment: @ScottS I don't use multiple `h1` tags on a page.. It is depend a page layout.. sometime I need to use `#main h1` or `#main .page-header h1`

Comment: @user791022--If you don't use multiple `h1` tags, then it is just best to style it without any reference to either `#main` or `.page-header`. Why would you _need_ to style it otherwise if the `h1` is unique?

Answer (score 0):

Hey now you can do this

```
#main .page-header h1 {
    color: white;
    font-size: 28px;
    line-height: 20px;
    margin: 12px 0 11px 11px;
}
```

Because

ID value is more than class and tag example

`#main` this is id and now this is value is `100`

`H1` this is HTML tag and this value is `1`

`.page-header` this is class and this value is `10`

Now define css carefully according to value.